# Clearing app data in android delete my UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I clear app data It will delete some of my UI.
eg.Column() and everything inside it
I've been searching on the internet but I don't know what I should do, so I'm asking you guys here.
this is my code

> I apologize if my code is disorganized or offensive to anyone. I'm a newbie at this. You can give me some advice.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            App {
                Screen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet(
                drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(0.7f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            )
            {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Column( //profile
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(180.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        Box( //padding
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(30.dp)
                                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                        )
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountCircle,
                            contentDescription = "Account",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .fillMaxWidth(0.5f)
                                .fillMaxHeight(0.5f)
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = "Profile",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            fontSize = 30.sp,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                        )
                    }
                    Box( //line
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(1.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth(0.8f)
                            .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                            .border(2.dp, Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(0.dp))
                    )
                    Box( //padding
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(10.dp)
                            .align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    Button(
                        onClick = {  },
                        content = {
                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                            ) {
                                Text(
                                    text = "Button",
                                    color = Color.White,
                                    fontSize = 18.sp
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Transparent),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(60.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth()

                    )

                }

            }
        },
    ) {

        Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            topBar = {
                CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                    title = { Text(text = "My App") },
                    colors = topAppBarColors(containerColor = Color(0xFF2196F3)),
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            scope.launch {
                                drawerState.apply {
                                    if (isClosed) open() else close()
                                }
                            }
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                                contentDescription = "menu"
                            )
                        }
                    },
                )
            },
            floatingActionButton = {
                FloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = { },
                    containerColor = Color(0xFF2196F3),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 30.dp, end = 10.dp)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.Add,
                        contentDescription = "Add new item"
                    )

                }
            },
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(it)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp, 0.dp)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .border(2.dp, Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp, 10.dp, 10.dp, 0.dp)
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .border(2.dp, Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                )

            }
        }
    }

}
```

How to make app know this is my UI not data to clear

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please be more specific about went wrong.